# How to publish messages into Document Store in webmethods IS without broker

Tags: local, publish, webmethods, document-types

I'm using webMethods 9.12.0. Only integration server and MWS is configured. I need to publish a message locally in IS. But when I tried to publish, its throwing error "document type not defined". Where to define document type?

Comment: Please add some details, maybe a screenshot of the publish step with your inputs. What document type do you want to publish? Do you have select "publishLocally"?

Comment: Hi Henning,

I misspelled when hardcoding the documentType path in pub.publish input. Now I can publish and subscribe the document locally. 

I have one more query

If I disable the trigger and publish a document, whether the document remains in documentStore until I subscibe or it will be deleted of the subscribing trigger is not found? 
I can see from the server logs that the document is rejected when the trigger is not available. 

"No Trigger available for incoming Document Sasikanth:testDoc. Rejecting Document "

Comment: Have you tried "suspending" the trigger, not disabling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable trigger documents will be discarded. But if you suspend it, documents will available when the trigger is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please sync your document type from Designer to Broker.

Use File> Sync Document types >All.

Now broker will know the type metadata of document

Thanks ,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the local connection name in the document type you are trying to publish. In properties of the document type set the connection alias name to DEFAULT(IS_BROKER_CONNECTION). Saving this should define the Provider definition to "Publishable Locally only" and allow you to use this "document type" name in the input of pub.publish service which should be able to publish the document locally.